# Spring HIbernate update part of Composite Primary key which is also part of Unique key

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a db schema which looks like the following

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `displayids_pivot` (
  `col_a` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `col_b` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `col_c` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created_at` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY `entity_record_unique_index` (`col_a`, `col_b`),
  UNIQUE KEY `entity_display_id_unique_index` (`col_a`, `col_c`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I want to update col_b in a record. I get an error when I try to update it as it's part of the primary key.
I also tried deleting and creating the record, but because of hibernates does an insert before delete, it causes unique field violation. 
How should I go about it?

I'm using the @Transactional annotation and not using the entityManager directly.

Comment: delete, then flush, then insert. But the correct thing to do would be to change the design: if something needs to be updated, it shouldn't be part of the primary key.

Comment: we want to make use of the clustered index here for optimization reasons. should I wire the sessionFactory in order to be able to flush the data?

Comment: No. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush--, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#flush--

Comment: great thanks!!. used the flush method on the JpaRepository.